# XML assignment - don't understand

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having trouble understanding an assignment regarding XML. I can't get hold of my professor and time is running out, so therefore I'm asking you here, if you can help me... I'm not very familiar at all with programming. 
The assignment is to create an XML document containing elements for describing bibliographic references (using Harvard referencing system). Then to create an XSLT document for extracting and representing all the bibliograpgic references from the XML document in a Web browser. The output page should contain the name of the referencing style chosen, the name of the resource (e.g., book, book with two authors etc.) and a bulleted list of examples belonging to that heading, formatted in Harvard, ordered in a descending order of the publication year.

I'm quite lost. I don't know if i'm supposed to create an XML schema? And how do I make a bulleted list? I'm studying to be a librarian, and this is a very small course in XML programming, so that's why I don't understand so much...

I would be so helpful if someone who knows this could explain some more how I'm supposed to do this. I'm sorry if thos question does not match here, but i'm so new to all this, I don't know where to turn.

All the best, Kim

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is too vague to be answered here.  Generally, we require a specific problem, with code examples of what has already been tried.

Comment: An XML schema is probably not necessary, although it can be helpful.  To create a bulleted list in HTML, use the `<UL>` and `<LI>` tags.

Comment: Create a simple xml with your data. For reference use google and you find lots of example of such. Then use xslt to transform that xml to an html page and display it in the browser. You can start from http://www.w3schools.com/ as the tutorials they provide on XSLT are provided in the same way

Comment: No, you don't need an XML Schema. Also, creating XML is not rocket science. XML is just text and can be written with any Text Editor (Notepad, UltraEdit, TextWrangler, JEdit...). There's a ton of information and tutorials on XML and HTML on the web - pick one that suits you. Start thinking about XSLT _after_ you've digested everything about XML.